# How to convert SVG map to PNG without losing border quality?

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I downloaded this svg [map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World-v2-2011.svg) and used ImageMagick to convert to PNG format. However, my output PNG images don't look very well: the white borders between countries almost don't show. On the other hand, the rendered versions on the Wikimedia site look great.

Is there any option I can pass to ImageMagick to prioritize borders?

Comment: I'd say this question was a better fit for the Super User channel of Stack Exchange.

Comment: There are no borders in [that svg image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/BlankMap-World-v2-2011.svg). All countries are drawn with a single path, and this example doesn't scale well. Zooming in/out in a browser show similar results to the ones produced by the vector to raster conversion.